# Executor block main thread - ANR triggered by main thread waiting for too long

Tags: java, android, service, executorservice, background-service

I was analyzing the firebase log (crashalytics) and I noticed a particular error related to the function posted below.

> jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park

> ANR triggered by main thread waiting for too long

```
 public class SendBackupData extends Service {
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
    private static final WriteInLogFile wil = new WriteInLogFile();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        executeOperation();
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::executeOperation, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    private void executeOperation() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        try {
            SemaphoreBKP.getInstance(context).goIn();
            if (new Utilities(context).checkConnection()) {
                File dataDir = new File(new Constants(context).getArchiveFolder(false));
                File[] listOfFiles = dataDir.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.startsWith("REPORT") && name.endsWith(".zip"));
                if (listOfFiles != null) {
                    for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
                        new FilesUtilities().splitBackupFiles(context, listOfFile.getName(), "arc");
                    }
                }

                File[] listOfFragments = dataDir.listFiles((dir, name) -> {
                    Pattern rexExp = Pattern.compile("(?:REPORT|\\G)(-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{8})(\\.zip)\\.[0-9]{3,6}\\.[0-9]{3,6}");
                    return name.startsWith("REPORT") && rexExp.matcher(name).matches();
                });

                if (listOfFragments != null) {
                    if (listOfFragments.length > 0) {
                        Arrays.sort(listOfFragments);
                        for (File currentFragment : listOfFragments) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            jsonObject.put("filename", currentFragment.getName());
                            SendDataProcedure sendDataProcedure = new SendDataProcedure("1", "transmitBackupDevice", jsonObject.toString(), context);
                            boolean requestStatus = sendDataProcedure.postDataFromBackupPushDTS(currentFragment.getName().trim(), false);
                            if (requestStatus) {
                                if(currentFragment.exists()) {
                                    currentFragment.delete();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            wil.WriteFile("SendBackupData - Exception: " + e.getMessage(), context);
        } finally {
            SemaphoreBKP.getInstance(context).goOut();
        }
    } }
```

I suppose the problem is related to the fact that I perform very "onerous" operations in the main thread and for this reason the user's UI is blocked.

How can I solve this problem ?

I need to run this piece of code in the background, every 50 min, this operation could be more or less long, there is no way to know in advance

Answer (score 0):

SemaphoreBKP goIn blocks the UI thread, move the related code to another thread, using such as AsyncTask.